# Distinct left join for foreign id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I need to find the latest 'message' from each 'user' and list them (like an inbox of conversations as per iPhone etc).

The fields in my messages table are:

`id|to|from|body|timestamp`

**to = the current users ID**

**from = sender user id**

How would I construct a query that gets the latest post for every distinct user where the 'from' field is unique? Obviously, the first condition is that the 'to' field matches the current users ID.

Each message from a distinct user should also **join** the user details into the results.

Also if you're able to demonstrate how this would work in CakePHP that would be awesome..! If not, just the SQL should do :)

Comment: You mean you want the list of latest messages sent TO current user or sent BY current user ??

Comment: to current user - so it's the current user's inbox :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL with subquery, like:

```
SELECT
  messages.*,
  max_stamps.max_stamp
FROM
  (SELECT 
    MAX(timestamp) as max_stamp, 
    `from` 
   FROM 
     messages 
   WHERE
     messages.`to`=$currentUser
   GROUP BY 
    `from`
  ) as max_stamps
  LEFT JOIN
    messages
    ON messages.`from`=max_stamps.`from` 
       AND max_stamps.max_stamp=messages.timestamp
```

-i.e. select max timestamps first in subquery, then use them for main table.

(*update*) If you want get maximum `id` value, then use it in `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
  messages.*,
  max_ids.max_id
FROM
  (SELECT 
    MAX(id) as max_id,
    `from` 
   FROM 
     messages 
   WHERE
     messages.`to`=$currentUser
   GROUP BY 
    `from`
  ) as max_ids
  LEFT JOIN
    messages
    ON messages.`from`=max_ids.`from`
```

*edit:* misunderstood `id`, `from` and `to` meanings. Tip: naming tables/columns with MySQL reserved words may cause troubles (at least you have to enclose that with backticks).

Comment: `AND message.timestamp = max_timestamps.max_stamp`?

Comment: Don't quite understand what you've put together here - I don't need to order by timestamps as ID's will work better for ordering and also there's no join of the Users table onto the query..

Comment: @MatBailie - yes, because can be multiple entries. Thank you

Comment: @Tim - this will select maximum timestamp for each user by `from` field for corresponding `$currentUser` in `to` field and then join main table data for that. Isn't it correct?

Comment: I need something like "get latest message (by ID) from unique users (FROM) where TO = current user ID"

Comment: @Tim, i.e. maximum IDs for each `from` with corresponding `to`?

Comment: @Tim - well, edited - it's the same query, actually, only field for `MAX` will differ, also no need in second `ON` condition since I think `id` is unique